# Text Strings in a fragment with setText

Tags: android, string, switch-statement, fragment

Thank you in advance for any help.

I would like to inject different strings in a Fragment but I'm not sure how.

The code that I borrowed to clunk things together at this point is:

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

```
int mCurrentPage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,false);
    TextView tv = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    tv.setText("You are viewing the page #" + mCurrentPage + "\n\n" +"\n\n" + "Swipe Horizontally left / right");       
    return tv;

}
```

This does what I want it to do, only I want to display different strings of text depending on which page it is on. I see in this example code that it is possible to update the page number (mCurrentPage), but I want to correlate that with different text strings.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please explain a bit better what you are using and add some supplementary tag (if you can find any suitable)?

Comment: Thank you, Daniele, for your kind request. I added a few more tags. I'm a bit overwhelmed. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the setText() into a switch case e.g:

```
switch(mCurrentPage){
case 0:
   tv.setText("string one");
break;
case 1:
   tv.setText("string two");
break;
}
```

Comment: This works and I have adapted--I'm a beginner, so there is probably a better way--but I was thinking that this way puts the text in the code, but I am actually hoping to find a way to have tv.setText refer to a string by id so that it can get that text from the strings.xml file, not pull up text in the code. Does that make sense?

Comment: for sure, you can also create a file strings.xml in your folder /res/values
there you can create some strings and use them in your code with: R.string.string_one
Read the android docu [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for further details